# Doctrine Nested Query

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I am trying to figure out nested queries in doctrine.

I have 3 Entities: Order (the orders), OrderStatus (Linking table between the orders and the possible statuses - contains a field called `createdTime`) , Status (list of all possible statuses, one field is `name`)

What I want to do is return a list of all the orders that have a latest status of `$statusName`

I know ive basically first got to get the latest status record for each order and then filter that by the `$statusName`. I've tried a number of different things but every time I think I'm on the right track and run into a brick wall.

What I currently have is this:

```
$subquery = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('max(os.createdTime), os')
    ->from('AppBundle:OrderStatus', 'os')
    ->groupBy('os.order');

$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');
$q->where($q->expr()->in('o.id', $subquery->getDQL()))
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

and I get the error:
`[Syntax Error] line 0, col 86: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got ','`

I'm not even sure if I got past this error if the query will do exactly what I want it to do yet but I can't get past this problem. Basically I want to produce a query similar to the SQL version:

```
SELECT o.*
 FROM Orders o 
 JOIN OrderStatus os
   ON o.order_id = os.order_id
 JOIN Status s
   ON os.status_id = s.status_id   -- JOIN your three tables

 JOIN (SELECT order_id, MAX(createdTime) as last_time
       FROM OrderStatus 
       GROUP BY order_id ) t       -- this will give you the last status
   ON o.createdTime = t.last_time   
 WHERE s.name = $statusName        -- select only the ones with $statusName
```

Comment: Just use a native query.. if you need objects get an array of ids from the native query and create a simple where id in ids query in DQL.